# alertar de vs alertar ante

Tags: preposiciones

Is there any difference in meaning between "alertar de" and "alertar ante" ? Are both equally usual? Examples:

- El gobierno alertó a la población de/ante la llegada de un huracán.
- Galán será recordado por el pueblo colombiano por alertarlo del/ante el peligro que representa los narcos.

Comment: I've voted to close for lack of effort. It's best to include a dictionary usage example.  For this, DLE is maybe not the most useful.  There are several other dictionaries in our Resources collection.  This is a good opportunity to experiment and find out which dictionary or dictionaries YOU find most useful. // You can also strengthen this question by including additional examples of these two usages.  The most useful usage examples to make it easier to help you are those that are part of a dialogue, which you include and link to.  You could try Google Books. Linguee is sometimes helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"alertar de" is used to introduce the thing one is warned about.

"ante" is equivalent to "in the face of" and does not necessarily introduce the risk or threat in question, but rather the conditions that may lead to the appearance of a risk:

- El gobierno alertó a la población **de/sobre** la posibilidad de derrumbes **ante** la llegada del huracán.

Comment: Is a sentence only with "ante" (i.e., without de/sobre) correct? I heard the second sentence in my question used with "ante" (Galán será recordado por el pueblo colombiano por alertarlo ante el peligro que representa los narcos) in the Narcos TV series.

Comment: Yes, it is correct.